# Excel formula for collapsing adjacent rows with a sum

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a spreadsheet with values like so:

```
blah   1    12
       2    12
       3    12
foo    1     6
bar    1     2
foo    1     6
       2     5
```

Numbers in the middle column range from 1 to 8; numbers in the right column range from 1 to 12.  The middle column is always in order with no gaps, but can reset back to 1 after any value.  The left column always has a nonblank (but not necessarily unique) value on a 1 row and a blank value on a >1 row.  The values for the >1 rows are *usually* the same as the 1 row, but not always (and I don't want to assume they are).

I would like to add a new column with a single formula that, for each row:

- if the first number is a 1, then sum all of the second numbers up to but not including the next row with a 1.
- if the first number is anything else, then output 0.

ie. the required output for the data above is:

```
36
 0
 0
 6
 2
11
 0
```

If it's easier, the sum could appear on the highest-numbered row of each subgroup instead of the 1 row (though I definitely prefer it on the 1 row).  But the row relationships have to be maintained -- it can't output only 4 rows.

Alternatively, the grouping decision could be based on the blank/nonblank column instead of the counting column; again, if that's easier.

Comment: Does it have to be a cell formula or could it be VB script?

Comment: A formula is preferred but VB script would be ok too.  I'm hoping for something not too large because the spreadsheet isn't saved as one; it's regenerated from CSV data periodically, so I have to re-enter formulae to calculate things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the table you as you give it is in A1:C7, in D1 and copy down:

`=IF(B1=1,SUM(C1:INDEX(C1:C$1000,IFERROR(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B2:B$1000=1,,),0),MATCH(10^10,C:C)))),0)`

Adjust the 1000 to a sufficiently higher row number if required.

Note that this solution assumes the values in column C are numeric, and not e.g. numbers stored as text.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure how that works, but it works. One change I did make though was to use a relative reference (`C1:C12` instead of `C1:C$1000`) since it's easier to define a maximum number of subrows before the 1 repeats than it is to define the maximum number of rows overall. Also this gives an error on the very last row, but that's easily worked around.